# MRTK (V2.5) always fails to deploy to Hololens 2 using the Build Window

Tags: mrtk

I'm using Unity 2019.4.11 and building to Hololens 2 over USB via the MRTK Build Window.  Everything seems fine until the point of install where I get a message about the wrong architecture.  It seems like it is trying to deploy to my PC instead of the device which is why it bails due to architecture (ARM64 when it thinks it should be x64).  Why is my device not being properly targeted?

[image]

Here are my build settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And here is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried deploying from the Device Portal (if connected by USB try 127.0.0.1:10080 in a browser) or through Visual Studio by clicking the "Open in Visual Studio" button and choose "Device" instead of "Remote Machine" then Build->Deploy?

I have never gotten deployment to work through Unity and have always just used a WiFi connection and deploying through either Device Portal or Visual Studio.

Comment: Deploying from the device portal works fine but it's not a very convenient workflow.  Everything does work if I doing everything through wifi (build all and install).  I get the impression that it's trying to deploy to a local simulator rather than going across the wire.